# What is the correct Content-Type for the Google Data syntax as used in the Google Contacts API?

Tags: xml, go, google-api, content-type, atom-feed

I need to read and update the Google Shared Contacts in a G Suite domain using Golang. Since there is no existing Go client library for this API, I'm having to interact with the API at the http level. Presently, I'm stuck on sending the correct `Content-Type` header.

Since the documentation at https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/domain-shared-contacts#Creating says to use `application/atom+xml` that was naturally what I tried. However, the response I receive is a `406 Not Acceptable` with a body message of "No acceptable type available". Omitting the `Content-Type` returns a 400 "Response contains no content type". Using `text/xml` returns a 415 with "Content-Type text/xml is not a valid input type."

```golang
    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", href, bytes.NewBuffer([]byte(body)))
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    req.Header.Set("GData-Version", "3.0")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "personnel-sync")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "text/xml")

    resp, err := g.Client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    bodyBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    bodyString := string(bodyBytes)
    log.Println(bodyString)
    log.Println(resp.Status)

    return bodyString, nil
```

The body I'm sending is the example in the documentation (link above) but it doesn't seem to matter at this point because an empty body gives the same response.

Answer (score 1):

Barely a minute after posting the question I spotted the problem. Sure enough, it wasn't the `Content-Type` header, but the `Accept` header. Removing that solved the problem. To be specific, Google was complaining that I requested `application/json` as a response type. The `Accept` header is apparently not even required.

Comment: Yes, I was in the middle of composing my answer hinting at, e.g. [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406). Basically, if you tell the server you `Accept` response in certain formats, and it's unable to provide its answer in one of them, it fails with 406 (if ti's compliant, which is, I admit, a rare thing in itself).

Comment: Note that the document you linked to says, among other things: «The Google server creates a contact using the entry you sent, then returns an HTTP 201 CREATED status code, along with a copy of the new contact in the form of an `<entry>` element.». This sort of hints at that it wants to return some XML back to you.